# How do I tell ggplot2 which factor to use for ordering?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe with more than one factor, for example:

```
df <- data.frame(foo = factor(c("joe", "jack", "jane", "jim")),
             bar = factor(c("A", "B", "A", "B")),
             baz = c(8, 3, 9, 9))
```

Now I want to get a barplot, but not in the alphabetical order of the "foo" factor, but orderd by the "bar" factor.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = foo, y = baz, fill = bar)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

will plot only ordered by the "foo" factor alphabetically. Also, can I order by a factor that is not even used by ggplot? For example if I had a third factor in the df dataframe?

Bonus question: Are there good tutorials on ordering factors? Every time I have to do this (for ggplot) I have to Google it and always get confused.

Comment: This question has been asked a few times.  See [this blog post](http://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2012/10/15/how-do-i-re-arrange-ordering-a-plot/) for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(foo, levels=foo[order(bar)]), y = baz)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Comment: A little bit of explanation on this would be nice ;)